# WSO2 APIM: How to implement "Design first" pattern? (Developers cannot test)

Tags: design-patterns, wso2, wso2-api-manager, user-roles

We are using WSO2 API 2.1.0 to deploy our business APIs.

Until now, we can follow, without problems, the pattern "Code first" for existing APIs. For example, we have an existing API REST in C#/NetFramework. In this case:
- Developer install a plugin, generate the Swagger file, and import ("Have an existing API") in API Publisher.
- Administrator deploy this new API, configuring the right backends (remember, the API already exists)

But now, we are going to deploy new APIs, and we want to follow "Design first" pattern. I mean, we want to describe the APIs using "Design a new Rest API" in publisher.

Our problem is that, in this case, the developer can generate code skeletons, but cannot test them, because they have the role "creator" only, and then, cannot deploy "prototype" or "test code" in any way (either in local PCs). Obviously, as API is in development stage, we cannot ask Publisher to publish it.

We cannot add publisher role for the developers, because, then, they can deploy directly in production environments.

NOTE: Initially we thought we have a security flaw, and we have confirmed with WSO2 staff that this is the intended behaviour for security. Developers cannot deploy event in prototype!

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The testing right after just creating or testing for the creator functionality is not there. Because in terms of WSO2 creator is always just creator so no rights for testing it out. Also, in current wso2 process of publishing the APIs there is no way of testing it before you publish.

The best thing you can do is to create another WSO2 instance on which developers can test out the APIs through WSO2. (That's what we do currently). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! We have already seen the proposal for life cycle in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment, but for us is not acceptable, because is hard and error prone in a DevOps environment